# React native expo sending notifications to users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, notifications, expo

I would like to send notifications to all users using my app. I have node server that can send them to all of them. I don't know if I should use expo push notifications or firebase cloud messaging or which service?

I tried to use expo push notifications but it requires having all devices tokens and it didn't work with Test Flight version of app after building and submitting it.

I tried to use firebase cloud messaging but it also didn't work even if I get device token and I generate server key in firebase console, after putting them to https://testfcm.com/ I do not get any notification on my simulator.

Comment: We use [`notifee`](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/integrations/fcm)'s integration with Firebase cloud messaging. You keep a token for each user's device updated in your database, and use it to send push notification. Might worth your effort to check it out. Also, push notification only works on Android emulator. It does NOT work on iOS simulator.

Comment: @FanchenBao how can I test it on iOS real device? To start app I have to use `npx expo start --dev-client`

Comment: We do not develop directly on an iOS device, so our way of testing is to literally install a pre-built app on an iPhone. But doesn't expo allow you to run the app on your device easily? Like what [this](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/run-on-device/) says.

Comment: @FanchenBao how do you install a pre-built app on iPhone? how do you build it?

Comment: "pre-built" might be a wrong term. We build a beta version for internal testing, and distribute it to actual testers' iPhones. That's how we install the app on iPhone. I believe the official way to do so is via [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). We, however, use [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/) for distribution. To build the app, we defer to [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/)

Comment: But I think if you can get the app to run on iPhone via expo, you don't have to worry about distributing a beta version just for testing push notification.

Comment: yes it would work but the issue is that expo does not have `@react-native-firebase/messaging` in their packages so I cannot use it because I see `Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist. 

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app.` this error

Comment: @FanchenBao and when I get above error, I can create a development build but it does not work on iPhone, only locally on SImulator so I cannot test notifications

Comment: So I don't know how can I use firebase messages in expo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252358/discussion-between-fanchen-bao-and-mickey).